# Swapping Nodes on a single linked list

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, linked-list

Since long back I have not used C or C++ ,so forget completely about Pointers. I'm familiar with C# and have written a basic version of this. Need to know whether I'm doing right/wrong?

Input:Linked List a->b->c->d->e->null

Output: Linked List b->a->d->c->e->null

We have to write code such that memory position is swapped and not the node value.

```
    public void SwapLinkedList(LinkedList<int> LL)
    {
        LinkedListNode<int> current = LL.First;
        while (current.Next != null)
        {
            int temp = current.Next.Value;
            current.Next.Value = current.Value;
            current.Value = temp;
            current = current.Next.Next;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Define 'swap'. This code puts first list value in the end of it correctly, is it what you want it to do?

Comment: Have a look at this thread

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535988/swapping-nodes-on-a-single-linked-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `LinkedListNode` order within a `LinkedList` can't be changed cause the `LinkedListNode` only allows a get on the `Previous` and `Next` properties. So to change the ordering within a `LinkedList` you can only swap the values (which allow a set).

So to get this to work, i would use some extension methods like these to make the swapping a little more general:

```
public static class LinkedListExtensions
{
    public static LinkedList<T> SwapPairwise<T>(this LinkedList<T> source)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

        var current = source.First;

        if (current == null)
            return source;

        while (current.Next != null)
        {
            current.SwapWith(current.Next);
            current = current.Next;

            if (current != null)
                current = current.Next;
        }

        return source;
    }

    public static void SwapWith<T>(this LinkedListNode<T> first, LinkedListNode<T> second)
    {
        if (first == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("first");

        if (second == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("second");

        var tmp = first.Value;
        first.Value = second.Value;
        second.Value = tmp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have reference on LinkedListNode prefered remove and add :

```
public static LinkedListNode<T> SwapWith<T>(LinkedListNode<T> first, LinkedListNode<T> second)
{
        first.List.Remove(first);
        second.List.AddAfter(second, first);
        return second;
}
```