# How can I swap two nodes inside linked list in C?

Tags: c, linked-list

I have this linked list

```
struct Link
{
    frame_t *frame;
    struct Link *next;
};
```

Now I want to replace two of it's nodes with the function swap() so for example swap(list, 4, 7) will give me

```
[1, 2, 3, **7**, 5, 6, **4**, 8, 9, 10]
```

for the list with the list with contents of

```
[1, 2, 3, **4**, 5, 6, **7**, 8, 9, 10]
```

What I tried doing was to use the nodes before the ones I actually need to replace but I got infinite loops and nodes that have been cut.

```
link_t* tmp = currPrev->next;
link_t* tmpTwo = linkToChangePrev->next;
tmpTwo->next = tmp->next;
currPrev->next = tmpTwo;
tmp->next = tmpTwo;
linkToChangePrev->next = tmpTwo;
```

What is the most effective way to change two nodes in linked list?

Comment: What is `frame_t` and why are pointers to it represented as integers in your examples?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535988/swapping-nodes-on-a-single-linked-list

Comment: Although one of the duplicate questions is tagged C++, the operational code is the same as C code (but the swapping function does contain a `cout << … << endl;` line, which is pure C++).  That covers the more general case; the pure C question covers a more limited case of swapping adjacent nodes.  Note that one of the suggestions in the C++ question is to swap payloads instead of swapping the pointers around — that has great merit since it can be done without needing to know anything about the nodes prior to the swapped nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit under-specified; what happens if the elements to be swapped occur more than once?

Assuming it's ok to just swap the first instances, I would definitely write code to do it in two steps:

1. Find the elements holding the data to swap.
2. Swap them.

Perhaps something like this:

```
const struct Node * find_node(const struct Node *list, frame_t *value)
{
  while(list != NULL)
  {
    if(list->frame == value)
      return list;
  }
  return NULL;
}

void swap(struct Node *list, frame_t *value1, frame_t *value2)
{
  struct Node *el1 = (struct Node *) find_node(list, value1);
  struct Node *el2 = (struct Node *) find_node(list, value2);
  if(el1 != NULL && el2 != NULL)
  {
    const frame_t * const f1 = el1->frame;
    el1->frame = el2->frame;
    el2->frame = f1;
  }
}
```

This will simply swap the two first found instances, if there are duplicates.

Comment: It would be better to show him duplicated question.

Comment: Shouldn't the function either take a Link** as input, or return the pointer to the list head?  The head of the list changes if one of the  items is the head.

Comment: I read the question as him wanting to find the items to swap based on the *values* not the position in the list.So you have to traverse the list to find the positions of both values and then swap

Comment: @tilz0R I disagree. The accepted answer in the duplicated question swaps the link elements. This answer just swaps the values held by the link elements which makes it a superior answer.

Comment: Oops, it seems I misunderstood the question completely, and wrote code to swap the wrong things.